# Detect device rotation/orientation in Ionic 4 without rotating app

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic-framework

Is it possible to detect rotation/orientation changes in an Ionic 4 app without actually rotating the entire app?

I'm using this:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/screen-orientation

I'd like to enter some callback on device rotation, not necessarily rotating the entire app. If I lock orientation, I lose the screenOrientation.onChange() emits. If I unlock rotation, my screenOrientation.onChange() emits, but the entire app webview also rotates.

Attempting something like this:

```
this.screenOrientation.unlock();
this.screenOrientation.onChange().subscribe(ev => {
        this.screenOrientation.lock(
          this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT_PRIMARY
        );
        // Do other stuff
});
```

makes the rotation jump between the two which looks bad.

Comment: I haven't worked enough with Ionic enough to know if you've got angular CDK or Material in there, but if so, you can get the current breakpoints using their BreakpointObserver https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

you should add this line to the config.xml in your project.

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```